# How do we know when an android version is going phase out and not maintain anymore in the near future?

Tags: android-versions

From the [security bulletin](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin) I can know that which version of Android is not being supported by Android anymore.

For example I can tell that Android version 7.1.1 and 7.2.1 are not being supported around 4th Nov 2019, by referring to the 4th Nov 2019 bulletin.

[image]

**Questions:**

1) Are there any ways to get the precise dates when Android 7.1.1 or 7.2.1 are deprecated?

2) Or are there any official announcement to get the date for Android 8.0 or 8.1 being deprecated beforehand? So we can plan accordingly to stop supporting that version for security reasons.

3) In wikipedia, old versions means it's unmaintained. But how to get this information from the official docs?
[image]

Comment: The Android version is not being phased out, [nearly 20% of users are on 7.x](https://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/) and they work, so do apps, including newly released apps that [must work with 5.x](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) (min sdk level) //Only security patches aren't provided any more for 7.x as you highlighted

Comment: isn't a version always deprecated with each new version? imho the precise date is date of new release

Comment: @beeshyams: `Only security patches aren't provided any more` - that is IMHO the common definition of a phased out OS. Just compare it with Windows XP which support has officially been dropped. That app developers still support older Android levels is something that is independent of the OS itself.

Comment: @Robert My take is different (without comparing with desktop OS, which is not an even comparison) - if newly released apps can't run on that then it is phased out (for now below 5.x). That's the time smartphone becomes a basic phone. Aside, I am not aware, if there is, a standard definition of what is phased out. One could argue that all earlier versions are phased out when a new version is released. I think *what constitutes phased out* is a good question to be asked and answered